# Sync Lock issue in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have worked with c# code for past 4 years, but recently I went through a scenario which I never pass through. I got a damn project to troubleshoot the "Index out of range error". The code looks crazy and all the unnecessary things were there but it's been in production for past 3 years I just need to fix this issue. Coming to the problem.

```
class FilterCondition
{
   .....
   public string DataSetName {get; set;}
   public bool IsFilterMatch()
   {
      //somecode here
      Dataset dsDataSet = FilterDataSources.GetDataSource(DataSetName); // Static class and Static collection
      var filter = "columnname filtername"
      //some code here
      ds.defaultview.filter= filter;
      var isvalid = ds.defaultView.rowcount > 0? true : false;
      return isValid;
   }
}

// from a out side function they put this in a parallel loop

Parallel.ForEach()
{
   // at some point its calling
   item.IsFiltermatch();
}
```

When I debug, `dsDataSet` I saw that `dsDataSet` is modified my multiple threads. That's why race condition happens and it failed to apply the filter and fails with index out of Range.

My question here is, my method is Non-static and thread safe, then how this race condition happening since `dsDataset` is a local variable inside my member function. Strange, I suspect something to do with Parallel.Foreach.

And when I put a normal lock over there issue got resolved, for that also I have no answer. Why should I put lock on a non-static member function?

Can anyone give me an answer for this. I am new to the group. if I am missing anything in the question please let me know. I can't copy the whole code since client restrictions there. Thanks for reading.

Comment: the problem lies within this call FilterDataSources.GetDataSource(DataSetName); you are writing to a resource that is shared. And you need to implement locking in it.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not thread safe.
You're accessing a static collection from multiple threads.

You have a misconception about local variables. Although the variable is local, it's pointing at an object which is not.

What you should do is add a lock around the places where you read and write to the static collection.

Comment: If i access static resource, the whole method will lose the thread safty ? how it is ? if it is with a static collection, how a simple lock solves the issue? the lock object should be static right ? Even i am also having the misconception with the local variable..

Comment: @user2613883 Thread safety isn't in a method's scope. It's about the safety of accessing the same resource. For each shared resource there should be a single lock to synchronize its access. So yes, the lock should be static as well in your case, and every thread should use  that same lock

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** the problem lies within this call

```
FilterDataSources.GetDataSource(DataSetName);
```

Inside this method you are writing to a resource that is shared.

**Solution:**

You need to know which field is being written here and need to implement locking on it.

Note: If you could post your code for the above method we would be in a better position to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of specific (not-stateless, not thread safe, etc) implementation of `FilterDataSources.GetDataSource(DataSetName)`, even by a method call it seems this is a static method. This method can do different things even return cached `DataSet` instance, intercept calls to a data set items, return a DataSet wrapper so you are working with a wrapper not a data set, so a lot of stuff can be there. If you want to fine let's say "exact line of code" which causes this please show us implementation of `GetDataSource()` method and all underlying static context of `FilterDataSource` class (static fields, constructor, other static methods which are being called by `GetDataSource()` if such exists...)

Comment: Its pulling a dataset from static dictionary, both dictionary and method are static.